# How to do an ORDER BY with a number in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, database, controller

I would like to run this SQL query in Laravel:

```
select * from CATEGORIE order by ID_CATEGORIE = 1, ID_CATEGORIE ASC
```

I tried with `orderBy("ID_CATEGORY", 1)` but it doesn't work, we can only put `"ASC"` or `"DESC"` in the `orderBy` of Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DB::table('CATEGORIE')->orderByRaw('ID_CATEGORY = 1, ID_CATEGORY ASC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: thank you it work well

Comment: ok. accept a correct answer.

Comment: Please don't copy the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use raw method `orderByRaw`.

```
->orderByRaw('ID_CATEGORY = 1, ID_CATEGORY ASC')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#orderbyraw

Comment: Thank you, it work well

Comment: Don't forget to accept a correct answer.

Comment: I can't accept both of the answers sorry

Comment: Yeah I know, try so sort answers by oldest and you will see that I was first...

Comment: @Pr4xy I really don't understand why you changed the accepted answer.